# Air App will not read local text file using openAsync/readUTFBytes on user (non-admin) mode

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air, filesystems

I am running an Air App I did for the desktop, from the actual installed executable already deployed in the machine (Not from Flash Pro / Flex dev. environment). For some reason the app will not read a text file stored in the same application folder unless I run my app as administrator from the OS.

When I run the app as admin, or within the development environment it works fine. Maybe this is related to some security issue? I read the adobe air documentation, and this should work...

I am using openAsync/readUTFBytes on user as shown here:

```
var continueGamesConnection:FileStream();
var continueFile:File = new File(File.applicationDirectory.resolvePath("continueGames.txt").nativePath.toString());

continueGamesConnection.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, openSavedGames);
continueGamesConnection.openAsync(continueFile, FileMode.UPDATE);

function openSavedGames(event:Event):void
{
    continueGamesConnection.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, openSavedGames);
    var content:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
    var loadedContent:String = new String();
    loadedContent = continueGamesConnection.readUTFBytes(continueGamesConnection.bytesAvailable);
    content.decode(loadedContent);

    variableX = content. variableX
    //etc, etc.

    continueGamesConnection.close();    
}
```

By the way, I have also, tried using FileMode.READ, and others, and it still gives me the same problem. Only works if ran on admin mode or from the dev. environment.

It's very frustrating, I tried reading other posts without any luck... What solutions do people use for this kind of problem?

I have seen that you can set the app to run as admin somehow, and I guess that could work. However, this should work just fine, since it doesn't seem to violate any of the security APIs of Air. Seems like an overkill. But even so, how do I do that?

You help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Just to be sure, if you trace out `continueFile.exists`, you get true, correct?

Comment: You don't usually have permission to the application directory with out elevated rights. Use `applicationStorageDirectory`

Comment: Thanks LDMS! 
Can you help me with some links to code examples? I thought doing this would create problems if the user chooses to install the application on a different folder...

Comment: work around is to load the file with urlloader then save anywhere outside of applicationDirectory (tempdirectory is fine) using filestream then read the file then delete the file (no duplicate)

Comment: Thanks BotMaster. Looks like I have to do just that, and set the File.applicationStorageDirectory as LDMS suggests. I will try it and report back later!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically for security reasons, applications do not have write permissions to the `File.applicationDirectory`.

It is recommended you use `File.applicationStorageDirectory` instead as that is the most appropriate place to save user data (such as a save game file).

Alternatively, you could also let the user browse to a directory with the `FileReference` class which may or not have permission.

Comment: Thanks again LDMS! I will try reading the documentation, make these changes and report back.

Comment: Does this code look right?  

 
`var continueFile:File = new File(File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath("savedgames/continueGames.txt").nativePath.toString());`   

Will this work across all desktop OS?

Comment: The resolve path method returns a File object, so you just need this: `var continueFile:File = File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath("savedgames/continueGames.txt"‌​);`    Though I'm not sure if it will create the **savedgames** directory automatically if it doesn't exist

Comment: Worked like a charm! THANKS SO MUCH!!! I wish I had seen this before: [Working with File objects in AIR](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118666ade46-7fe4.html#WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118676a4c56-7fc6)

Comment: I should add that it didn't create any files or directories, but I simply checked if(continuefile.exists) and if doesn't, I create it by  opening a new file stream and using writeutfbytes.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are using a Windows SO, the problem that you have is about user access restrictions to  folders C:\Program Files and C:\Program Files (x86) and there is nothing you can do from Flash or AIR to solve it. You could modify you security settings by right click on the folder or you should simply avoid using the app folder to store anything